# Concat rows in pandas DataFrame with another text

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I need help with realisation of the following logic: While grouping a DataFrame I want certain columns to be concatenated with another text. For example:

Input:

```
id | col1 | col2
---|------|------
1  |  A   | 12
1  |  B   | 43
---|------|-----
```

After applying something like
`df.groupby(id).concatrows("text_"+col1+":"+col2.astype(str))`,
the desired output should be:

```
id | new col
---|-----------------------
1  | text_A:12;text_B:43   
---|-----------------------
```

So it should be kind of `";".join()`, but with more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be the following:

```py
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda g: ';'.join('text_' + g.col1 + ':' + g.col2.astype(str)))
```

Output:

```
id
1    text_A:12;text_B:43
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to concatenate col1 and col2 first before concatenating groups,

```
("text_" + df['col1'] + ":" + df['col2'].astype(str)).groupby(df['id']).apply(';'.join)
```